# First image in my array is not displayed in collectionview cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
 cell =[self.imgCllvw dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(!cell)
        {
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        NSDictionary *tmpDict = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"img"]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *imge= [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = imge;
              });
        });
        cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
        cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0/255.0 green:214.0/255.0 blue:214.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

                return cell;
}
```

First image is not loaded and if I scroll the collectionview images are displayed and I have used autolayout for collectionview

Comment: One more thing, stop referencing `row` in `UICollectionView` delegate and dataSource methods. Reference `indexPath.item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try async downloading of image rather than sync, something like this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  cell =[self.imgCllvw dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  if(!cell)
  {
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  }
  NSDictionary *tmpDict = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"img"]];
  NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (data) {
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      if (image) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          MyCell *cell = (id)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          if (cell)
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        });
      }
    }
  }];
  [task resume];
  cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
  cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0/255.0 green:214.0/255.0 blue:214.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: but still if I load more images its getting shuffled

Comment: That will happen as in collection cells are reused. Are storing downloaded image data? If not store it in array/core data and check before downloading if image data exists then assign it to cell image view else download

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **dispatch_async, mainqueue** you can use **dispatch_sync**, like this,

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    cell.imageView.image = imge;
          });
```